# Error while trying to export gee data and display appears (Error code: 3)

Tags: google-earth-engine

when I export the GEE data it appears

> Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type.
> Expected type: Image. Actual type: FeatureCollection.
> (Error code: 3)

can you help me solve it

following is the script code

```
var maskL8 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('BQA');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4).eq(0);
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var composite = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
        .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')
        .filterBounds(geometry)
        .map(maskL8)
        .median().clip(geometry);


//visualisasi citra
var RGBTrue = composite.select(['B2', 'B4', 'B7']);
var RGBparam = { min: 0, max: 0.2,};
Map.addLayer(RGBTrue, RGBparam, 'TRUE');

var aoi = vegetasi.merge(badan_air).merge(lahan_terbangun).merge(tegalan)
.merge(rumput).merge(industri).merge(kosong).merge(sawah);

var bands = ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'];

var training = composite.select(bands).sampleRegions({
collection: aoi,
properties: ['lc'],
scale: 30
});

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train({
features: training,
classProperty: 'lc',
inputProperties: bands
});

var classified = composite.select(bands).classify(classifier);

Map.addLayer(classified,
{min: 0, max: 7, palette:['darkgreen','blue','red','darkblue','green','orange','yellow', 'brown']},
'classification');

//Klasifikasi

var uji_aoi = uji_akurasi_vegetasi.merge(uji_akurasi_badanair).merge(uji_akurasi_lahanterbangun).merge(uji_akurasi_tegalan)
.merge(uji_akurasi_rumput).merge(uji_akurasi_industri).merge(uji_akurasi_kosong).merge(uji_akurasi_sawah);

var validasi = classified.sampleRegions({
  collection: uji_aoi,
  properties: ['lc'],
  scale: 30,
});
print(validasi);

var akurasi = validasi.errorMatrix('lc', 'classification');
print('Confusion matrix', akurasi);
print('Overall accuracy: ', akurasi.accuracy());

var class_areas = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1000*1000).addBands(classified)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'code',
    }),
    geometry: geometry,
    maxPixels : 500000000,
    scale: 30,
  }).get('groups');
  
print(class_areas);

//legenda
var panel = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-left',
    padding: '5px;'
  }
})

var title = ui.Label({
  value: 'Klasifikasi Tutupan Lahan',
  style: {
    fontSize: '14px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    margin: '0px;'
  }
})

panel.add(title)

var color = ['darkgreen','blue','red','darkblue','green','orange','yellow', 'brown']
var lc_class = ['Vegetasi', 'Lahan Terbangun', 'Sawah', 'Badan Air','Lahan Kosong','Rerumputan','Industri','Tegalan']

var list_legend = function(color, description) {
  
  var c = ui.Label({
    style: {
      backgroundColor: color,
      padding: '10px',
      margin: '4px'
    }
  })
  
  var ds = ui.Label({
    value: description,
    style: {
      margin: '5px'
    }
  })
  
  return ui.Panel({
    widgets: [c, ds],
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
  })
}

for(var a = 0; a < 8; a++){
  panel.add(list_legend(color[a], lc_class[a]))
}

Map.add(panel)

// Export the image, specifying the CRS, transform, and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: geometry,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample_transform',
  region: geometry
});
```

I try to export data but the result is always the same. Is there an error in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Add `maxPixels` parameter to the `Export.image.toDrive()` function.

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: geometry,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample_transform',
  maxPixels:   1e13
  region: geometry
});
```